# Shortcut in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

If I place the cursor on the method `playSound()` on this line: `soundManager.playSound(1);` Is it possible for Eclipse to open and jump to this method in that class? I pretty sure, but I haven't used Eclipse for some time and forgot some of the shortcuts.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ctrl + mouse click on that method

Answer (score 2):

You can always use key assist option in the help menu of eclipse to find the shortcut keys.

> Ctrl+move over method  : Open Declaration or Implementation